# How to iterate over tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I need to change a sign from positive to negative within a tuple that's in a dictionary. So if I have 'position: (3,4)' I need to change it to 'position: (3,-4)'. This is what I have but it's not working.

```
for k,v in positionD.items():
    v = (v[0],-v[1])
    positionNewD[k] = v
```

Comment: Did you want to modify `positionD`?

Comment: How is it not working? Your code seems fine...

Comment: Are you getting an exception thrown. If so, what is it? Syntactically, your code is correct.

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tems'

Comment: What you posted isn't what you're running, because what you posted works. Did you mispell items() in the actual code?

Comment: If that's the error you're getting then this code isn't the cause.

Comment: *sigh* Human error, not code. I messed up on the dictionary creation by forgetting parentheses. Any way to delete this question?

Comment: "forgetting parentheses"? Putting on my psychic guessing hat for a moment, does that mean you typed `positionD = dict` where you wanted `positionD = dict()`? If so, consider the simpler alternative: `positionD = {}` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (requires Python >= 2.7):

```
positionNewD = {k: (x, -y) for k, (x, y) in positionD.iteritems()}
```

For older versions:

```
positionNewD = dict((k, (x, -y)) for k, (x, y) in positionD.iteritems())
```

Comment: There's no need for the `[]` in your "older versions" variation - omitting it uses a generator expression which can be more efficient since it doesn't have to construct a list.

Comment: Unless of course it's a *really* older version that doesn't support generator expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3

```
positionNewD = {k: (x, -y) for k, (x, y) in positionD.items()}
```

... as iteritems() has been renamed items()

http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists